# Unusual Behavior with NIC Interrupt Moderation Disabled

Tags: centos, tcpdump, interrupt

OS: Centos7

I disabled interrupt moderation,

```
ethtool -C eno2 rx-usecs 0,
```

and then started capturing on that interface using tcpdump. The dump file was growing as expected.

Maybe an hour later the tcpdump process was still running, and I could see the interface was receiving packets (via ifconfig) but the packets were no longer being captured by tcpdump.

I stopped tcpdump (showed no drops) & started again, but still no packets were being captured, even though ifconfig was showed the interface was still receiving packets.

So I enabled interrupt moderation,

```
ethtool -C eno2 rx-usecs 20,
```

and started tcpdump again... packets were being captured.

I then disabled interrupt moderation, started tcpdump again, and packets were still being captured. Checked back some time later and the same problem had occurred... no packets were being captured - even though the interface was receiving packets.

I noticed that ifconfig showed that the 'NIC' had dropped an additional packet each time I realized packets were no longer being captured.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.